# SpringBoot MethodInterceptor Auto Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop, spring-restcontroller

## How to intercept **@RestController** methods using **MethodInterceptor** in SpringBoot?

Prior to using springboot, I have a simple Interceptor that logs the execution time of a bean method. Simply intercepts all spring bean methods through a default proxy definition.

```
@Component
public class MethodTimer implements MethodInterceptor {
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {
    final StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
    stopWatch.start(methodInvocation.getMethod().toGenericString());
    try {
        return methodInvocation.proceed();
    }
    finally {
        stopWatch.stop();
        System.out.println(stopWatch.prettyPrint());
    }
  }
}
```

The spring configuration where **com.mypackages** contains the beans and the MethodInterceptor implementation.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackages" />
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator">
  <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The configuration above is loaded via

```
@ContextConfiguration("/application-context.xml")
```

Method executions are logged, everything seems to be working, life is good.

## Moving to SpringBoot

I use the same code, switched to annotations (eliminating the *.xml) configuration

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.mypackages" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
```

Added a constructor to the MethodTimer with System.out.println() to make sure that the Interceptor has been loaded by spring boot

```
public MethodTimer() {
  System.out.println("MethodTimer - Constructor");
}
```

And yes, it was loaded and created as *"MethodTimer - Constructor"* is found in the console logs.

However, none of the @RestController methods are intercepted. Below is a simple Rest Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class HelloWorldService {
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String sayHello() {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

Even tried creating a pure spring bean via **@Component** and **@Autowired** it in the **@RestController** to see if that pure spring bean is intercepted, but it was not intercepted as well.

A simple Test service bean. The test() method should be intercepted.

```
@Component
public class TestService {
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("TestService.test()");
  }
}
```

Revised RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class HelloWorldService {
  @Autowired
  private TestService testService;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String sayHello() {
    testService.test();
    return "Hello World!";
  }
}
```

Notes

1. The **MethodTimer** was loaded as the constructor was called showing the System.out.println log in the console, it seems however spring boot did not automatically determine that this bean/component is implementing *MethodInterceptor*.
2. The simple Spring Bean annotated with **@Component** bean was not intercepted.
3. The Rest Controller annotated with **@RestController** was not intercepted.
4. I have tried adding **@Component**, **@Service** in the RestController, it did not work.
5. I have tried tried **@EnableAutoConfiguration**, adding **spring.aop.*** configurations in the **application.properties**, did not work.
6. Tried using SpringBoot version **1.5.4.RELEASE**, does not work.

I know I can always try to use Aspect as shown in the spring-boot-sample-aop example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-aop

But not able to use previous spring code and configure it with springboot is just too lame. If **MethodInterceptor** and **DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator** is not supported anymore in spring boot, it should have been deprecated

Comment: How about HandlerInterceptors ? https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html

Comment: Hmmm, RestController is really a syntactic approach of writing servlets so they are still HTTP request/response in general, so yes that can be use or even a generic servlet filter can do the job as well. But I would rather want the logs to show method names and parameters rather than letting the developers figure out that this url requests http://xxxx took xxx secs and let them locate the method themselves.

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` != `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` they are 2 different mechanisms (well the same mechanism but operate on different metadata). Either use `@Aspect` and write a proper aspect (the recommended way) or register the `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` manually as a bean.

Comment: Yes indeed they are different. And yes, tried registering the DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator as a bean in the application config plus calling the setter proxy target class plus setting the application.properties but still to no avail.